# asp.net multiple sites / facets mvc

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, project

Good day,

I am currently developing an asp.net mvc 4 site.

I have made a Front end site so far, which a user will be prompted with when they go to my url.  Now I want to make a back end which certain users can then login and access all sorts of functionality, settings, options etc.

Now ideally you would make the front end and the back end in two different projects in Visual Studio. But now how would I link them together? For example if i am already logged in in the back end then the front end should still know that i'm logged in. So in essence it must still be one site. I just want to have the different components / facets in different projects.

Reason I want to do this is for organization of the project in VS and to try and modulate it as much as possible.

Can I do this?

Comment: Can you expand on your question - specifically the distinction between the two projects. Is this a single website for which you are also creating an admin area, or a common admin area for multiple websites? Why you do want or need to have them in separate projects?

Comment: It is a single site which i want to add an admin area. Reason I want to make them separate projects is for organization and separation of files. The admin part has different theme, html css, models etc. So it would make sense to isolate it. Also the project will become very messy and cluttered when the sites grow and functionality is added. I dont want to have classes and files from both sites all mixed together in one class. Also they will need different system settings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would most likely be possible to create these as separate projects with common authentication tokens (I can think of at least one- albeit hackish- way to do this), based on your requirements I would strongly suggest a single project with an admin **Area** to separate (and namespace) off your models, views and controllers for the admin functions.

Although you do not specify which version of ASP.NET MVC you are working with, [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) have been available within MVC since version two.

This would allow your admin related views, controllers, models and other classes to be logically grouped together under /Areas/Admin in the project structure (which can spend most of it's time collapsed if you want to keep things hidden away) and also for any classes to be namespaced to SiteProject.Admin.Class which will keep them separate from those in the main site.

This is no different conceptually if you think about it to having them in a different (referenced) project and then references to items as AdminProject.Class. The area has its own route definition, giving you flexibility to handle routes differently from the main site, and its own Web.config allowing additional or changed settings.

The advantage of using areas is that you don't have to do any extra work around authentication, you can deploy the project as a single entity and you don't have to worry about routing requests between projects (I'd imagine a sub-domain would have been the most straightforward way to separate requests in the separate project model). Any shared views or partials will also be available in the admin area if you want to keep the same look and feel (although you could of course use an entirely different layout if you wanted), and you will be able to reference static resources (such as images, scripts and stylesheets) using application relative URLs (tilda - "~/Content/styles.css"). Anything application specific like Session will also be available to you, which could be incredibly important (although it is of course possible to have a common session store for multiple applications using something like SqlSessionProvider).

If you have a Pluralsight subscription K Scott Allen discusses areas in his MVC2 course [ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc2) (although his Views obviously don't use Razor syntax, everything else in those chapters remains relevant).

If you want to have your business entities and logic in different projects then that is both appropriate and to be encouraged for future re-usability, but in this case I feel it is much more sensible to have related items together to keep things DRY and simple.

Comment: Thanks for that. It sounds like Areas is exactly what i am looking for.